# How can I generate elf file with debug info using arm-none-eabi-ld?

Tags: linker, arm, elf, arm-none-eabi-gcc

I'm trying to remote debug compiled code for arm on qemu. But I cannot set breakpoints based on symbols.

Below is my `mk` script:

```
ARM=arm-none-eabi
QEMU=qemu-system-arm

$ARM-as -o ts.o ts.s -g
$ARM-ld -T t.ld -o t.elf ts.o
$ARM-nm t.elf
$ARM-objcopy -O binary t.elf t.bin

dd if=t.bin of=flash.bin bs=4096 conv=notrunc

$QEMU -s -S -M realview-pbx-a9 -kernel t.bin -nographic -serial /dev/null
```

I actually got ts.o with symbols, since the output of `arm-none-eabi-nm -a ts.o` is:

```
00000000 n .ARM.attributes
00000004 d Array
00000000 b .bss
00000000 d .data
00000000 N .debug_abbrev
00000000 N .debug_aranges
00000000 N .debug_info
00000000 N .debug_line
00000000 N .debug_str
00000018 t loop
00000000 d N
0000002c d Result
00000000 T start
00000004 t stop
00000008 t sum
00000000 t .text
```

But the output of `arm-none-eabi-nm -a t.elf` is:

```
00010048 t Array
00010018 t loop
00010044 t N
00010070 t Result
00011160 T stack_top
00010000 T start
00010004 t stop
00010008 t sum
00010000 t .text
00000000 a ts.o
```

You can see that t.elf doesn't have symbols. So I guess something was wrong.

By the way, I tried `gdb ts.o` to debug, actually I could use symbols in this situation but the position of breakpoint was wrong since I changed the start section location. See `t.ld`:

```
ENTRY(start)
SECTIONS
{
  . = 0x10000;
  .text : { ts.o }
  .text : { *(.text) }
  .data : { *(.data) }
  .bss  : { *(.bss)  }
  . = ALIGN(8);
  . = . + 0x1000; /* 4kB of stack memory */
  stack_top = .;
  .debug_aranges  0 : { *(.debug_aranges) }
  .debug_info     0 : { *(.debug_info .gnu.linkonce.wi.*) }
  .debug_abbrev   0 : { *(.debug_abbrev) }
  .debug_line     0 : { *(.debug_line) }
  .debug_frame    0 : { *(.debug_frame) }
  .debug_str      0 : { *(.debug_str) }
  .debug_loc      0 : { *(.debug_loc) }
  .debug_macinfo  0 : { *(.debug_macinfo) }
}
```

EDIT: I found that if I link another .o file generated by .c file like below:

```
arm-none-eabi-as -mcpu=arm926ej-s -g ts.s -o ts.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=arm926ej-s -g t.c -o t.o

arm-none-eabi-ld -T t.ld ts.o t.o -o t.elf
```

Then t.elf *has* debug symbols for the *c* file, but why I can't get debug symbols for the *assembly* file?

Answer (score 0):

> You can see that t.elf doesn't have symbols.

We can see that it *does* have symbols. It just doesn't have *debug sections*.

> See `t.ld`

Well, your linker script tells the linker to ignore all the `.debug_*` sections, so that's *exactly* what it did.

See the `DWARF2` section [here](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Linux-i386-Boot-Code-HOWTO/internel_lds.html) on how to preserve these sections instead.

Comment: I added all the code in `DWARF2` section in my linker script, but it seemed still not work, maybe I did something wrong?